# Confused as to what settings MySQL 5.7 is using on Windows 10

Tags: mysql, windows-10, bugzilla

I just installed MySQL 5.7 on Windows 10. I am intending to run bugzilla on this computer, so I'd like the settings from [this bugzilla mysql settings page](http://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing/mysql.html#mysql), which are

```
max_allowed_packet=16M
ft_min_word_len=2
```

When I run `mysql --help` from `cmd`, I get a line that says

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
C:\WINDOWS\my.ini C:\WINDOWS\my.cnf C:\my.ini C:\my.cnf C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.cnf
```

None of those files exist until `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini`, which is where I added the settings from above. HOWEVER, if I open `mysql -u username -p` from the same window, I get

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
+--------------------+---------+
| Variable_name      | Value   |
+--------------------+---------+
| max_allowed_packet | 4194304 |
+--------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ft_min_word_len';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| ft_min_word_len | 4     |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And if I do `mysql --help` again, I get a line that says

```
max-allowed-packet                16777216
```

So I'm really confused. Am I logging into different mysql installs or something? Current full `mysql --help` [here](https://gist.github.com/nguillermin/d7c0e438ea1b0002d081dfc1b51fcd94).

Comment: do the above and issue a `select @@version`, you may have multiple instances of the server going, and without a `-P portnumber` you cmd line maybe pointing to the wrong daemon

Answer (score 0):

Find the spot where your `my.ini` is first picked up. A typical spot will be in the `basedir` visible with

```
select @@basedir;
```

Do the same for `@@datadir` and write those values down in case you make changes and want to undo what you have done. Such as messing it up and your data is not pointed to upon startup. You log file will tell you if it is broken.

Note too my comments above about specifying the port number with command line tools with a `-P` (uppercase).

For the `my.ini` you will need to Open as Administrator to make changes there anyway. Then perform a server restart. (mysqladmin).

Depending on your actual mysql version, attempt to modify, say, the verbosity level. And continue until you isolate where the file you want is picked up for your variables you wish to load on startup. Note in my below it suggests I have two servers running. Which I do on ports 3306 and 3307 for 5.6 and 5.7.13, respectively.

```
[mysqld]
basedir=C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\
datadir=C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\Data\\
port=3307
log_error_verbosity=2

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER
```

When you first setup the server on Windows, it is highly likely that you don't even have a `my.ini` that is active. There is a default stub not Live. And the values are merely baked in. It took me a while to realize there was truly no file loading anything until I found the spot.

Comment: I know it doesn't start with a default config. I copied the my-default.ini to my.ini in `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7`

Comment: And you restarted and checked versions

Comment: "Find the spot where your my.ini is first picked up." Yes, that is the question. Its not the basedir spot, which is where I first looked.

Comment: "And you restarted and checked versions" Yes, its `5.7.14-log`